# How to insert keyboard key graphic representations into your document?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I'm working on a document describing keyboard shortcuts in GNOME and want to make text better looking than: ALT + TAB.  A common way seems to be like in this thread where the buttons appear to be within the text:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465681

Is this possible in LibreOffice in a proper way, or is it just inserting images inline?  That doesn't seem like it would work every well with changing font size, etc. later, so I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert *real* push buttons that don't do anything by following steps 1 thru 6 outlined at https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Inserting_and_Editing_Buttons. But that approach, as well as inserting inline images, would be awkward because you'd have to worry at least about sizing, anchoring, and wrapping of surrounding text.

The approach you appear to be trying to avoid seems much more palatable, so long as you're not looking to exactly duplicate to Stack Exchange look.

As an example to demonstrate that it's workable, I did the following by applying the same Character formatting settings to each key word. This involved changing font family and size, setting light gray highlighting, adding a gray border, and changing left and right border padding from 0.02 to 0.06...

[image: LibreOffice Writer keyboard key representation example]

To make things easy, the settings could all be done with a single button press by creating a macro that could be applied to selected text. And since the result is just formatted text, there are no sizing, anchoring, or text wrapping issues to worry about.

One other option, as an alternative to significant text formatting, is to acquire and use a keyboard font, such as that discussed at [How is the Keyboard font automatically styled as keyboard-like keys for the letters in Alt, Shift, Ctrl, Esc, and Backspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613006/how-is-the-keyboard-font-automatically-styled-as-keyboard-like-keys-for-the-lett). That would only require changing to that font to type in key representations.

Comment: Extremely thorough response and options, thank you.  I like the bordering option the best, and didn't realize you could do that without embedding text boxes, which is a bit of a pain.

Comment: Rather than a macro, I was able to create a named style "Keyboard button" which had all these changes.  Now, when I select any word, I can just right click on it and apply that style.  Perfect!